# jQuery how to get select change the image,ajax work in multiple form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, forms, select

i need to select change some data and change image in own form
each from will have own preview image.
each image will get **attr** name "imagePreview" from selected the option.
if nothing in **attr** or imagePreview="0" will do nothing

here some of my working scrip but when I change option all image preview in DIV tag will change not just in the form...
please help me to make it work >.<

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.choose').change(function(event) {
  var update = $(this).prev();
  //------
  var src = $("option:selected").attr("imagePreview");
  $(".imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
  //-----
  $.post('select-change-ajax2.php', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function(data) {
    update.html(data);
  });
});
});
</script>
```

**html form**

```
<form>
<div class="imagePreview">
   displays image here
</div>
( etc data this data not change )
 <div class="update">Default Data</div>
    <select name='selected' class="choose">
        <option value="1" imagePreview='/images/1.jpg'>1</option>
        <option value="2" imagePreview='0'>2</option>
       </select>
       <input type='hidden' name='do' value='go' />
</form>

<hr />

<form>
<div class="imagePreview">
   displays image here
</div>
( etc data this data not change )
 <div class="update">Default Data</div>
    <select name='selected' class="choose">
        <option value="3" imagePreview='/images/1.jpg'>3</option>
        <option value="4" imagePreview='0'>4</option>
       </select>
       <input type='hidden' name='do' value='go' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the elements that matter (`.imagePreview` and the `<option>`) [relatively](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.choose').change(function(event) {
    var form = $(this).closest("form"),
        update = form.find(".update"),
        src = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("imagePreview");
    form.find(".imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
    $.post('select-change-ajax2.php', form.serialize(), function(data) {
      update.html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

The key is changing `$("option:selected")` and `$(".imagePreview")` to be relative to the changes element, rather than selecting the first/all they find, respectively.

Before it was finding the *first* selected `<option>` in *any* `<form>` and *all* `.imagePreview` elements, not by using [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) we're finding the elements you want relative to the `<select>` (the `this`) that changed.

Comment: Thank you again Nick it's working well u forgot some "var" and ";" ... so , i just put the new code from you again in the next answer :D

Comment: @Choo - You can declare multiple varibles at once with a comma, i'll change the indentation to make this more apparent.